# Tiny Mce and JQuery Dialog (FireFox and Chrome Issue)

Tags: jquery, dialog, tinymce

Tiny Mce works fine outside of a jquery dialog box on all browser but when it is addded to a dialog box it breaks on every browser except ie.

Does anyone know why.

IE - It works Fine
FIREFOX, CHROME - THE TEXT EDITOR PART STOPS WORKING

Im not using anything special on the editor like modal :true. Just a basic dialog that wont work with firefox or chrome. Has anyone else experienced this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            tinymce.init({
                mode: 'none',
                selector: "textarea",
                // General options
                menubar: false,

                toolbar: "bold,formatselect,preview,underline,|,styleselect |,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,code",
                //toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                ]
            });

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $("#opener").click(function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    g <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        dfg <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
    <div class="demo-description">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you get any javascript errors